# Proof by cases inequality with abs. value and min max

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, real-numbers, formal-proofs

Help me to figure out how to make a proof by cases of the following statement:

> For all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$
>   if $| x − y | < \min(x, y)$ then $\max(x, y) < 2 \min(x, y).$

A proof by cases is of the schema:

> case 1 : ...
>
> > sub-case a: ...
>
> case 2: ...

Comment: Well, say. $x>y>0$.  Then you are asked to show that $x-y<y\implies x<2y$.  Can you do that case?  The other cases are similar.

Comment: Just do it: Case 1: $x < y$ then $\min(x,y)=x, \max(x,y)=y,$ and $|x-y|=y-x$.  So prove $y-x<x\implies y< 2x$.  Case 2: $x=y$ then $\min(x,y)=\max(x,y)=x=y$ and $|x-y|=0$. So prove $0<x=y\implies x=y<2x=2y$. And case 3: $x > y$ and then $\min(x,y)=y;\max(x,y)=x$ and $|x-y| =x-y$ so prove $x-y< y\imples x< 2y$.

Answer (score 2):

**First case** $\min(x,y)=x$:

Then $\max(x,y)=y$ and $\max(x,y)<2\min(x,y)$ becomes to $y<2x$.
From $|x-y|<\min(x,y)=x$ we have $-x < x-y < x$, the **left** part says $y<2x$.

**Second case** $\min(x,y)=y$:

Then $\max(x,y)=x$ and $\max(x,y)<2\min(x,y)$ becomes to $x<2y$.
From $|x-y|<\min(x,y)=y$ we have $-y < x-y < y$, the **right** part says $x<2y$.